# Fill in missing week numbers from SQL dataset

Tags: arraylist, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a query that will return data like this:

```
Year    WeekSub
2013    52
2013    53
2014    1
2014    2
2014    4
2014    7
```

Notice for 2014 weeks 3, and 5-6 are missing.

What I need to do is add these items to an array where the array will have Year+WeekSub and I need to fill in the missing values as well as make sure I don't create a 54th week while doing this.  When I get to the 53rd week in a given year, I need to add the next week (week 1 of the new year) to the array.

I have some code I am developing to try and do this but it is starting to get very complicated and I wonder if there is a simpler, more efficient way.

```
If IsArray(arrRawData) Then
    For RawData = 0 to UBound(arrRawData,2)
        If strYearNum & ":" & strYearNum <> arrRawData(0, RawData) & ":" & arrRawData(0, RawData) Then

                If CInt(arrRawData(1, RawData)) - CInt(strWeekNum) = 1 Then
                    If Not dicHeader.Exists(arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData)) Then
                        dicHeader.Add arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData), arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData)
                    End If
                Else
                        If strWeekNum + 1 < 54 Then
                            If Not dicHeader.Exists(arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) + 1) Then
                                dicHeader.Add arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) + 1, arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) + 1
                            End If
                        Else
                            If Not dicHeader.Exists(arrRawData(0, RawData) + 1 & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) - 53) Then
                                dicHeader.Add arrRawData(0, RawData) + 1 & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) - 53, arrRawData(0, RawData) + 1 & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) - 53
                            End If
                        End If
                End If

                    If Not dicHeader.Exists(arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & CInt(arrRawData(1, RawData)) + 1) Then
                        dicHeader.Add arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & CInt(arrRawData(1, RawData)), arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & CInt(arrRawData(1, RawData))
                    End If
                    If strWeekNum + 1 < 54 Then
                        If Not dicHeader.Exists(arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) + 1) Then
                            dicHeader.Add arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) + 1, arrRawData(0, RawData) & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) + 1
                        End If                              
                    Else
                        If dicHeader.Exists(arrRawData(0, RawData) + 1 & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) - 53) Then
                            dicHeader.Add arrRawData(0, RawData) + 1 & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) - 53, arrRawData(0, RawData) + 1 & ", Wk " & arrRawData(1, RawData) - 53
                        End If
                    End If

            strWeekNum = arrRawData(1, RawData)
            strYearNum = arrRawData(0, RawData)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: what is that weeksub?

Comment: weeksub is the week number of the year.

Comment: as i do not know for what you Need this i only can guess... but have you looked at the vbscript function DatePart?